# Early Forth for personal computers

Tags: programming, compilers, forth

What were the earliest Forth programming language implementations for 8-bit personal computers?  Was it FIG Forth?  Or a predecessor?  Or some other development?

Why did Forth lose its relative popularity in usage after the advent of 16/32 bit personal computers?

Comment: Forth lost its popularity because it was always known as a "*Write-only*" language.  It was impossible to document and didn't support comments.

Comment: @Chenmunka Huh? If those are actual rumors, then yeah, they would hurt it's popularity. I don't entirely disagree with the "write-only" reputation. Forth can be written just as obliquely as Perl or any other language. Further adding to that is its stack-oriented ("reverse Polish") logic flow that many find foreign. However, your second sentence is entirely false. Forth has two comment types, parenthetical ( in-line ) and backslash \ comment to end of line

Comment: @RichF:  The Forths that I (briefly) used didn't support either of those comment formats.  I'm glad that there were better ones around.

Comment: @Chenmunka Classically, there was even a third type of code documentation, the **shadow screen**. Forth code was originally written in 64-character by 16-line screens, stored on disk as numbered blocks. Blocks 1000 to 1999, say, were assigned to interpretable Forth code. Then 2000 to 2999 were documentation screens.  I.e., 1000 (in this example) above every code screen was its documentation screen. // Since more complex file systems are used today, shadow screens are no longer necessary.

Comment: @Chenmunka those must have been pretty ancient, or "tiny" (as in "tiny C") versions. Even FIG-Forth in 1978 supported both parenthetical and backslash comments.

Comment: @RichF:  I'm talking 1973/74.  Well before '78 we'd blacklisted Forth as an unusable language.

Comment: I have a Jupiter Ace. I believe the version of FORTH on it is a custom one. It is innovative in that it has both a compiler and a decompiler, and can perfectly reproduce the original source code from the compiled program. For this reason, it doesn't need to store source and object copies of the program in the Ace's limited RAM; it instead stores one or the other depending on if you're editing your program or running it, and converts between them almost seamlessly.

Comment: @Chenmunka Wow, that is "ancient". In 1973 I was taking FORTRAN at UW Madison, delivering my programs to the computer center as a deck of 80-column IBM cards. Even at 2 in the morning, it might take them an hour or two to actually run your program. We got a print-out of the program, even if it had failed. I'm assuming you had serial terminals. (I'd seen them at Cray, located near where I went to high school in Chippewa Falls, WI.) It's hard to imagine using Forth without at least that level of interactivity. Sigh, I guess you don't get a 2nd chance to make 1st impression.

Comment: Just a word of use: Forth is alive and well, and in active use - for deep space probes. The radiation-hardened IBM RAD series of single-chip-computers, which are most popular as deep space probe systems, use Forth as their machine language.

Comment: @Muzer Actually, decent Forths mostly included disassemblers. There were some pretty primitive Forths around, however, including my dialect on the 6809 that I need to test. (I now regret never having turned that into a full development environment.)

Comment: FYI, Forth still has a strong following over at the 6502.org forum.  http://forum.6502.org/viewforum.php?f=9

Comment: I wrote a very fast Forth compiler (based on FiG I think) in 6809 assembly back in the early/mid 80s. It supported comment structures quite happily. So I think that alothoigh early Forth may not have been user friendly, it certainly became much better.

Answer (score 22):

I believe [FORTH Inc.](https://www.forth.com/) provided the first microcomputer version:

> FORTH, Inc.'s microFORTH was developed for the Intel 8080, Motorola 6800, and Zilog Z80 microprocessors starting in 1976. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)#History)

It wasn't until 1978 that the FIG-Forth model became available, based on the 6502 implementation developed by one of FIG's founders, Bill Ragsdale. [Ref](https://www.forth.com/resources/forth-programming-language/)

---

My professional programming career began with FORTH, Inc.'s version for the PDP-11 family. It gave 100% control of everything all of the time. While it was a multi-tasking and multi-user system, the implementation was such that these features were co-operative.  One user or bad application could disrupt the others.  Everyone and every application had 100% control of everything all of the time.  It sounds contradictory, but in a non-networked environment of people working together, this was a very efficient system with little operating system overhead.

That was the key to early Forths. The operating system was Forth. The development environment was Forth. The language was Forth. The applications were Forth. (You weren't writing separate programs so much as making Forth bigger.)

Computer scientists were probably horrified at these concepts. Sure it was compact, efficient, quick in both development and execution, and many implementations were free. But it wasn't safe. It wasn't structured. It gave everyone 100% control of everything all of the time. Anathema!

**Forth lost its popularity because it is seldom taught, and it breaks too many rules. Running under an operating system does give advantages, such as networking, GUI, and a large number of available applications for the computer. But it has lost part of what made it unique.**

My next professional job added Unix computers to the Forth stuff I was doing. Partial control of some things when Unix feels like it. The paradigms were opposite, and it felt disconcerting switching from one to the other. Forth, of course, was available on Unix, but as a program controlled by Unix. (This is how most Forth's are today, running under a larger operating system.) If you really like the language, that's cool.  Most managers won't allow its use though, because even as a slave app, it is different to almost everything else, and the number of Forth programmers is relatively small.

**Formality is another reason it lost its popularity. Sure it results in fast development, but fast development is not part of modern programming philosophy. "*Know what you're going to do before you do it*" is.** Plan everything out ahead of time. Forth was designed for interactive, iterative development. Try something. Fix it, tweak it, improve it. Okay, the telescope can now spin at the speed, direction, and to the location desired. An hour later, move on to controlling the angle of the telescope relative to the ground. Don't already know what you are going to do.  Just do it.  (I know there are places that encourage iterative development techniques, but as far as I know it is uncommon, especially in large companies.)

Comment: Right! Forth aspired to be a complete operating environment in which educated users would manipulate their collection of routines to produce the novel results they need that day. The way people use UNIX is comparable except that each routine is a separate binary and therefore languages in use are an orthogonal concern. So part of the reason for the death of Forth is simply that consumer computing went in a different direction; people use them mostly for consumption, rather than program creation. And those users who want to spend their time combining and building tend to do so multilingually.

Comment: Your description of Forth reminds me of one of my favorite quotes from Dan Ingalls' [Design Principles Behind Smalltalk](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/smalltalk.html): "An operating system is a collection of things that don't fit into a language. There shouldn't be one."

Comment: @Tommy I wouldn't say Forth is "dead" -- more like "unpopular and hidden". It is hard for me to imagine a better system for embedded system software development. The problem is so few people know anything about it, and they would rather use something they know. But there still are commercial implementations out there, meaning people still make money with it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I love the quote. The tide of momentum probably makes it tough for anything that goes against the flow, though.

Comment: @RichF the designers of the Open Firmware, which originated at Sun but survived in Macintoshes until the Intel transition, agreed with you. That's a tight, embedded system from the modern-enough era that used Forth. The Intel Macs use UEFI instead of the Open Firmware just because the different chip vendor came with a different firmware interface. There was no motivating technical reason to eliminate the Forth.

Comment: [Additional information](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/0-starting-forth/#Introduction_for_Professionals_Forth_in_the_Real_World) from the online version of Leo Brodie's "Starting Forth".

Comment: @Draakhond I hadn't seen that updated introduction, having read only a more vintage copy, but I'm not sold on the "Forth is fast" angle; besides the constant calling and returning, when I last checked the Forth dictionary was specified to be a linked list. So all lookups are O(n) by design, and expect hefty cache misses. The two things combined certainly suggest compactness to me, but not speed. EDIT: great book though. A recommended read for the heavy focus on factoring.

Comment: IIRC, Forth *was* fast compared to any non-assembly programming language (Basic, Logo, Pascal P-machine, et.al.) that could be developed and ran well on PCs with less than 64k of memory.  Once over 64k of DRAM became affordable (to typical IBM PC buyers), Forth lost that advantage.

Comment: @Tommy I fully agree concerning the excellence of Brodie's _Starting Forth_. His follow-up, _Thinking Forth_ is of equal or greater excellence, moving on to the "whys" from the "whats" and "hows". // [Section 3.3 of the Forth Standard](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage) says that the form of the dictionary is not specified by the standard. Of import is what it does, not how it does it.  **JForth** is a commercial implementation for the C= Amiga. (I used it on a well-received open-source GUI Utility, *IconJ*.) It is designed with a JSR dictionary, not a linked list.

Comment: @RichF they must have fixed that up later; per e.g. https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/9-forth-execution/ the dictionary is explicitly a linked list — each dictionary entry, however arranged in that implementation, has a 'link' entry that "contains the address of the previous definition in the dictionary list", and "[a]t search time, tick (or bracket-tick-bracket, etc.) starts with the most recent word and follows the “chain” backwards, using the address in each link cell to locate the next definition back.". Those are presented as absolute facts, not implementation specifics.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I'm not going to say the aforementioned JForth generated the fastest non-assembly Amiga code, but it was pretty darn fast. From a [review by Jack Woehr](http://www.softsynth.com/jforth/woehr.html): "*The entire body of a JForth JSR-threaded definition is executable MC68k code. Every definition ends in an RTS.*" Yes, there is still overhead, but don't all high-level languages have some degree of that?

Comment: @Tommy It's likely a lot of implementations still use linked lists. They're simple and very efficient space-wise. But perhaps the Standard authors eventually decided that **what** it does is more important than **how** it does it. Back to JForth, it still has enough of the traditional dictionary structure that a Forth decompiler operates much the same for it as one would for linked-list implementations. I'm not sure it would still work if you optimized your program, though.

Comment: @RichF : After there was enough (PC, Mac, Amiga) DRAM for the optimization pass of a decent C compiler, the compilers eliminated a bit of redundant code (extra jumps and returns as per Forth words), and Forth no longer had an HLL speed advantage.  Most performance oriented hobbiests and engineers moved to traditionally compiled languages (C, even VB, etc.)

Comment: @hotpaw2 Heh, as I just implied to Tommy, you can optimize JForth code as well. Technically (and depending on what the optimizer actually does) that might change your "Forth program" to a "program written in Forth". I'm not sure such a distinction ultimately matters, though.

Comment: @Tommy You only have to look up words when interpreting or compiling, so the design of the dictionary doesn't affect runtime performance.  A linked list will do fine in most cases.

Comment: @RichF Regarding "JSR dictionary".  There are two separate things here: the data structures used for the dictionary, and how words are compiled.  "JSR threading" would be using JSR instructions to to call words, but that has nothing to do with what the dictionary looks like.

Comment: _"Computer scientists were probably horrified at these concepts."_ Actually, no. The idea of the language being the OS, "[not] writing separate programs so much as making [the system] bigger," and being "designed for interactive, iterative development" are exactly what [Lisp machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine) are all about, and Lisp developers have always tended to be more "computing-sciency" types.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I agree that Forth and Lisp have much in common.  But the 1980s environment when Lisp Machines were being produced has become a lot more bureaucratic. A couple decades ago I went through an ISO 2000 quality standard certification at the company where I worked.  I could see how its focus on "process" would be important where there were large programming teams, but our company typically had 1 to 3 programmers on a project. General precepts like "know what you are going to do before you do it" and "design everything before writing a line of code" just didn't fit.

Answer (score 10):

From the Gforth manual section [Appendix B Authors and Ancestors of Gforth](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Origin.html#Origin):

> A team led by Bill Ragsdale implemented fig-Forth on many processors in 1979. Robert Selzer and Bill Ragsdale developed the original implementation of fig-Forth for the 6502 based on microForth.
>
> The principal architect of microForth was Dean Sanderson. microForth was FORTH, Inc.'s first off-the-shelf product. It was developed in 1976 for the 1802, and subsequently implemented on the 8080, the 6800 and the Z80.

Regarding Forth on the 6502, Forth Inc's [Forth programming language, history and evolution](https://www.forth.com/resources/forth-programming-language/) states:

> Bill Ragsdale, a successful Bay Area security system manufacturer, became aware of the benefits of microFORTH, and in 1978 asked FORTH, Inc. to produce a version of microFORTH for the 6502. FORTH, Inc. declined, seeing much less market demand for microFORTH on the 6502 than the more popular 8080, Z80 and 6800 CPUs.
>
> Ragsdale then looked for someone with the knowledge of microFORTH and intimate familiarity with the 6502 to port a version of microFORTH to the 6502. He found Maj. Robert Selzer, who had used microFORTH for an AMI 6800 development system on an Army project and was privately developing a standalone editor/assembler/linker package for the 6502. Selzer wrote a 6502 Forth assembler, and used the Army’s microFORTH metacompiler to target compile the first 6502 stand-alone Forth for the Jolt single board computer.

Comment: FORTH, Inc. seems to have made a strange misjudgement about the popularity of CPUs; by 1978 the 6502 was far more popular than the 6800, and arguably more popular than the 8080. As well, FORTH was ideal for embedded systems and new embedded systems would be more likely to use the much cheaper 6502 chip unless there were other factors requiring an 8080 or 6800. (One might be able to argue that the 8080 had a better architecture for some things, but certainly not the 6800, crippled as it was by having a single index register. This wasn't fixed until 1979 with the 6809.)

Comment: I can't really comment on the industrial popularity of the 6502 at the time, but in my surplus crate-digging I'm yet to find a 6502-based embedded system. 6800 (or more likely, Hitachi 630x), Z80 or even 1802 systems turn up more often.

Answer (score 9):

Forth was available for many of the microcomputers (and some minis) that could be called personal computers when they shipped. Engineers often constructed small Forth Kernels as the engineering department's debugging monitor for new hardware (including many things not PC), and, depending on the culture of the people they were working for, they often made their work available in the early users groups.

Non-engineers often did not know what do with Forth interpreters, and passed over them looking for BASIC.

Also, managers who didn't understand Forth would not allow the engineering debugging monitor to ship in the product, arranging for a conventional one to ship with the hardware instead. Managers who did understand Forth also took it out, to avoid giving the customers too much for their money.

Now, Forth kernels were useful as post-fix integer calculators, but you really wanted a much more complete development environment. That is part of what drove the creation of the fig-Forths -- helping to demonstrate a common set of definitions that could be used, with minimal porting, to construct a full IDE. (Line editor IDEs were still useful back then because we hadn't been spoiled by full-screen editors.)

Reasons Forth did not catch on? It didn't really lose its popularity, it was just totally eclipsed by the Bill Gates machine.

I think there may have been deliberate misinformation, because some thought Forth would not bring the customers back for the add-ons, etc. Gotta have that business plan that guarantees a cash flow.

But there was also a lot of terminology difference. Today we can describe a Forth as an interactive symbol table with fundamental math libraries. The detail of the split stack doesn't even hit radar level any more. It should, because of the now-well-known problems of the stack crash/smash, but I'm not willing to predict that common sense will prevail, even now. (Especially now.)

The terminology and concept differences were deadly.

"Instruction threading" is generating a list of mixed effective op-codes and procedure calls in a virtual machine that cached the return address to reduce call overhead. But people interested in Forth got all tangled up in details of the threading and wasted a lot of time in work that was mostly theoretical exercises in the limits of call optimization and pre-optimized static register usage patterns. It is actually valuable in an academic sense or in a CPU architecture research environment, but it didn't push product out the door, and sometimes made enemies that didn't need to be made.

(I was one of those who wasted considerable time on that.)

"Words" vs. functions/procedures was another terminology difference which was confusing. "Dual stack" was another. I think a better term now would be "split stack".

Postfix notation is a conceptual gap. You could (and some did) write a prefix or infix interpreter for Forths, but that mostly raised hackles. Other purist issues came up about the use of the stack -- whether to limit direct access to the swap/rot range or allow a generalized pick that could pull in operands from arbitrary depth.

Splitting the stack made post-fix natural and simple to implement in the interpreter, but there was really no real reason to avoid infix or prefix. Shoot, the standard word for defining functions is prefix in standard Forth.

The funny thing is that the non-Forth community has wasted a lot of effort support something called a stack frame that is mostly there to give the interleaved stack enough structure that you can safely use the interleaved stack to hold variables. With the split stack, all of the complexity of the stack frame goes away. If you really want a stack frame, it's just pushing the parameter stack pointer with the instruction pointer. The frame pointer can actually be just thrown away on return in most run-times if the stack is split.

And the other funny thing is that the split stack is still ignored as the primary first step in really dealing with the security problems of stack corruption. If you don't want the return address overwritten, don't store it with the parameters and variables.

The 64K boundary was another point of conflict in concepts. In other languages it was not such a big issue, but many early Forths made use of the 16 bit modularity, and there were some purist arguments about that, as well.

Considering the size of a bit-mapped display frame buffer, no one should ever have taken the 64K arguments seriously, but hind-sight is twenty-twenty.

That brings up one more sticking point, which you refer to.

Moving from 16-bit to 32 required a bit of abstraction, and Forth has always been a bit stand-offish about abstraction. To convert a 6800 or 6809 Forth to the 68000, for instance, many just kept the 64K memory model. (Can you imagine?) The actual conversion required going back through the source code carefully, looking for instances of "2 +" sequences that marked incrementing to a next address and changing those to "CELLWIDTH +" or some such. Not just that, of course, but you really had to understand the low-level source and you really had to take time doing it.

For people who had done it before, implementing a new Forth for a new 8-bit CPU was quick and painless when you had a full IDE to start with. Almost all the heavy lifting was high-level. But you couldn't do that when you jumped from 16-bit addresses to 32-bit. You could still do a lot of high-level, but you had to slow down, and the market was cut-throat enough to scare you about slowing down when you weren't sure how much you'd have to slow down.

Now is that more than you thought you wanted to know about this?

Comment: I appreciate your detailed response and knowledge base. // Wasn't an early controversy within the Forth community based on the value of TRUE? IIRC, one of the early provisional standards defined it as -1 (all bits set). Prior to that, some Forths used 1. The -1 choice was ultimately correct. ( **6 TRUE AND** returns FALSE should TRUE have a numeric value of 1, but effectively true if it is -1 -- consistent behavior both boolean and binary.) However, the newly required value broke badly written code, code that had treated TRUE as a numeric value with mathematical operators.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the arguments that went the rounds. But -1 is only correct for a **set** *true* given a set of assumptions found in, as you say, most of the common Forth code in circulation. 1 is correct give the assumptions used in most of the common C code. Both C and Forth share the common **read** definition of *non-zero* for true, which is also correct for both. -- I have found that trying to straddle both contexts has at times given me headaches. :-/

Comment: _Today we can describe a Forth as an interactive symbol table with fundamental math libraries._ This is a brilliant insight; there are several other good ones in this answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding postfix notation, I think that while it is an issue, it's certainly not the primary issue, likely not even a major one. The continuing popularity of the Lisp family from the 70s onward and the recent increase in popularity and acceptance (as demonstrated by Clojure) show that mainstream developers do learn to accept non-infix notation if they perceive other advantages in the system.

Answer (score 8):

> Why did Forth lose its relative popularity in usage after the advent of 16/32 bit personal computers?

It didn't have any relative popularity as an 8-bit computer programming language at least, not amongst hobbyists. All 8-bit microcomputers except one came with a BASIC interpreter and BASIC was a much easier language to learn. The one computer that didn't come with BASIC was the [Jupiter Ace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Ace) which had Forth built in instead. The Jupiter Ace was a commercial failure, partly because it didn't have BASIC.

Why was Forth not a success (as a general purpose language)? There are tworeasons, in my opinion:

1. Forth is a hard language to learn for an absolute beginner. Many people who bought 8-bit micros had never done any programming and so were having to learn how to program. If you're struggling with the basic (sorry about the pun) concepts, an unfamiliar notation is an added difficulty too far.

   BASIC programs were lists of instructions in almost English. They weren't much of a stretch from, say, a recipe or a list of directions. Forth programs were lists of words in reverse Polish notation, which can be tricky to grok.

   Also, expressions in BASIC were not too far removed from expressions as taught in maths at school. Also, also The concept of a stack can be quite tricky to grasp. You can do a lot with BASIC without knowing what a stack is.
2. The BASIC monoculture was self sustaining. In the age of 8-bit computing, everybody knew BASIC. If you had a problem with a BASIC program, somebody could help you solve it. If you bought computer magazines, they tended to have program listings in the back that you could type in. These were almost invariably in BASIC.

Forth is a great language with a small footprint, but it is quite low level and definitely quirky. It was never going to be a mainstream success.

Comment: The relative popularity of Forth was certainly not zero.  Before the IBM PC, Forth was popular enough for the Forth Interest Group to have regular and well attended meetings in the SF Bay Area, as well as there being multiple in-print publications on Forth(s).  But that ended around the time the PC and Mac were introduced.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Don't kid yourself, it wasn't popular in the mainstream world of eight bit microcomputing. The existence of interest groups and publications does not mean everybody - or even a significant proportion of people - was using it. And the SF Bay area is not the World.

Comment: I'm guessing that Forth died with the relative popularity of C getting better.

Comment: When I was using Sun workstations in the late 90s, the diagnostic language of the machine was Forth.  I don't know whether that is still the case.  To understand Forth, you need to understand the double stack and indirect threaded code.  Once you've worked that out, it is quite simple.

Comment: @cup Sun used Openfirmware for the initial bootloader (analagous to the BIOS in a PC). It was implemented entirely in Forth.

Comment: There was another computer with Forth built in: The Micronique Hector HRX: http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?st=1&c=142

Comment: The Canon Cat (developed by Raskin's Information Appliance company after he left Apple) had an OS and apps written in its built-in Forth.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Forth was incapable of being a mainstream success. People learn what they need to and get used to it. I think it was the wide and easy availability of cheap Basic interpreters (much of which was due to Microsoft Basic) and concomitant network effect that sealed Forth's fate.

Answer (score 6):

That's kind of two questions in one; as to the latter: one of the big benefits of Forth is that it produces threaded code: every new word (/function) is very nearly just an ordered list of of other words to call. So the output tends to be very compact, but not very speedy. Once you've got more RAM, it stops being quite so useful a trade-off.

It's also unusual in being stack based. Postscript is the last surviving  stack-based language, as far as I'm aware, and it's rarely used for much beyond data storage. So its swimming against the tide probably didn't help.

As to the former: there were at least two Forths for the Apple II by 1979 — so predating most of the competing machines — Apple Forth by Cap'n Software and AppleFORTH by Programma International. Given the similar names it's probably safe to assume independent but concurrent development, and a lack of preceding competitors.

Comment: There are lots of stack based languages that other languages compile into.  For instance p-code, used by Pascal, o-code and a-code by BCPL, bytecode by Java.  The difference is Forth had 2 stacks: one for return addresses and one for the parameters.  Really got me confused when I was implementing a compiler in C.

Comment: Also available for the Apple II, circa 1979, was gforth, reportedly derived from FIG-Forth, reportedly derived from microForth.

Comment: I think I know what you mean when you say that Postscript is used mostly for "data storage," but I have trouble thinking of it in such passive terms.  Postscript documents that I've had experience with are often quite "active" in computing the printed page, not just conveying it.

Comment: Note that the IL for .Net is also (at least partially) stack based.